# Computed properties in Vuetify Datatable rows

Tags: vue-component, vuetify.js, computed-properties

I am using Vuetify and Vuetify/Datatables for a website.
Now I want some `computed` properties on every row of the table.

To do that I would probably need to make a component of the `<template>` element and add computed properties to that component. I tried `<template is="myComponent" :m="props.item">` but this did not work.

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  hide-actions
  class="elevation-1"
>
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
    <td>{{ THIS_VALUE_COMPUTED }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: re-read: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#is

Comment: What type of data are you trying to compute and what is the outcome you are looking for?

Comment: I did find a solution, see my answer below. I want to perform calculations on the values of every row in the table, like adding fat, carbs and protein together. I wanted that without having to loop through an array, because in the past that caused me trouble.

Comment: Why not use a method taking the parameters you want to work with rather than a computed property?

Comment: @SimonD that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 7):

it's a bit aged question but this might work, it is from the vuetify 2.0.19 documentation. Here you can do a computed value on one of the single properties of your table.

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  hide-actions
  class="elevation-1"
>
   <template
            v-slot:item.calories="{ item }" >
    {{ THIS_VALUE_COMPUTED }}
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: Much simpler method, it works for me. Thanks ! I don't figure out how to use a computed property though. I can't leave `item` not used, I have to pass it as an argument. Thus, I can only use a `method`, cause when I use a computed properties, let's say `{{ myComputed(item) }}`, I get `myComputed is not a function` in my console. I switched to a `method` and it works like this for me.

Comment: hey @JrmDel, would you have a full codepen to illustrate this. I can't make it work, using computed or method, it doesnt work. Would you be able to show what is the syntax of myComputed() method ?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use computed properties by including an extra component (with computed properties) and an extra `<template>` element. I am not realy happy with havign two `<template>` elements inside each other but this was the only way to get this working. Any better solutions are still very welcome.

([Working codepen example](https://codepen.io/haaiee/pen/BrjdGa?editors=1010))

JS (a modification on the Vuetify Datatable example):

```
let myComponent = Vue.component('my-component', {
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log('mounted', this.item)
  },
  computed: {
    COMPUTED_PROPERTY: function() {
      return this.item.fat +
        this.item.carbs +
        this.item.protein
    }
  },
  template: `<tr>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.calories }}</td>
    <td>{{ COMPUTED_PROPERTY }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.iron }}</td>
  </tr>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted: function() {
    console.log('loaded')
  },
  components: { myComponent },
  data: () => ({
    pagination: {
      sortBy: 'name'
    },
    selected: [],
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        align: 'left',
        value: 'name'
      },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat + Carbs + Protein (g)', value: 'total' },
      { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
    ],
    items: [
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        carbs: 24,
        protein: 4.0,
        iron: '1%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
        calories: 237,
        fat: 9.0,
        carbs: 37,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '1%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Eclair',
        calories: 262,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 23,
        protein: 6.0,
        iron: '7%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Cupcake',
        calories: 305,
        fat: 3.7,
        carbs: 67,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '8%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Gingerbread',
        calories: 356,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 49,
        protein: 3.9,
        iron: '16%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Jelly bean',
        calories: 375,
        fat: 0.0,
        carbs: 94,
        protein: 0.0,
        iron: '0%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Lollipop',
        calories: 392,
        fat: 0.2,
        carbs: 98,
        protein: 0,
        iron: '2%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Honeycomb',
        calories: 408,
        fat: 3.2,
        carbs: 87,
        protein: 6.5,
        iron: '45%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Donut',
        calories: 452,
        fat: 25.0,
        carbs: 51,
        protein: 4.9,
        iron: '22%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'KitKat',
        calories: 518,
        fat: 26.0,
        carbs: 65,
        protein: 7,
        iron: '6%'
      }
    ]
  }),

  methods: {
    changeSort (column) {
      if (this.pagination.sortBy === column) {
        this.pagination.descending = !this.pagination.descending
      } else {
        this.pagination.sortBy = column
        this.pagination.descending = false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">
  <v-data-table
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    select-all
    :pagination.sync="pagination"
    item-key="name"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
      <tr>
        <th
          v-for="header in props.headers"
          :key="header.text"
          :class="['column sortable', pagination.descending ? 'desc' : 'asc', header.value === pagination.sortBy ? 'active' : '']"
          @click="changeSort(header.value)"
        >
          <v-icon small>arrow_upward</v-icon>
          {{ header.text }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </template>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <template :active="props.selected" @click="props.selected = !props.selected">
        <my-component :item="props.item">
        </my-component>
      </template>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</v-app>
</div>
```